# How do you make a flipswitch on the right corner of a fixed header in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I have tried the following:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
<h1>My Page</h1>
<label for="nfcSwitch" class="ui-hidden-accessible">NFC:</label>
<input data-role="flipswitch" name="nfcSwitch" id="nfcSwitch" data-on-text="NFC on" data-off-text="NFC off" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

but it shows the flipswitch on the left, under the `h1`

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1>My Page</h1>
    <div class="switch">
        <label for="nfcSwitch" class="ui-hidden-accessible">NFC:</label>
        <input data-role="flipswitch" name="nfcSwitch" id="nfcSwitch" data-on-text="NFC on" data-off-text="NFC off" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.switch
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTGE6/)**

Comment: thank you, it works, but not perfectly. the 'off' state is almost hidden.

Comment: ...Labels are ugly, but that's another issue